# favicon won't show up on desktop shortcut, only in tab

Tags: favicon

I'm using chrome, my favicon works in the browser tab.
However, when move URL to desktop to create shortcut, the chrome logo appears instead.
This is the link I used...

```
<link rel="icon" type = "image/png" href="img/favicon16.ico" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type = "image/png" href="img/favicon32.ico" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type = "image/png" href="img/favicon96.ico" sizes="96x96">
```

Comment: I have also cleared the cache in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Favicon is not used for that. You need to add a web app manifest file, that points to the correct icon as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest

Edit: I might be wrong and the manifest.json might only work for mobile

Answer (score 0):

Desktop chrome shortcuts do not have the same icon as a favicon and will open in the program you have as the default for that extension, in this case chrome. You can sometimes customize desktop shortcut icons.